# View with image and tableview does not look the same on phone like it look on Interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a view that contains an ImageView and a tableview . The Image it is ok - good resolution , In interface builder it looks ok : half of screen with image , half of screen with tableview . The width and height are set properly . When I run on phone (iphone 4 with 5.1 ) it does not show the image just the table on full screen . 
I ve done another xib and in that case another strange behavior it shows the image very small after blank after the table . I don t know why on IB it looks good and on iphone not . The images are good quality so I don t think it is because of them .

Comment: Are u changing the property of image and tableview in coding by anychance?

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: no , in code i just create the table data source

Comment: I want the screen to contain a image - that is static half of screen , and a table view . I have 3 screens like this . For one it works . Fot the other 2 it does not work well . 1 case: it shows table on full screen . second case: it shows just a part of image , after black after the table view . In interface builder it look normal as I want to look , on iphone it does not look the same .

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Attributes inspector and check what is the size type selected for your xib file. Change it accordingly. It is by default set to Retina 4 full screen for now, change it to free form and set to standard iphone 4 size, and one more thing are you using AutoLayout ???

Comment: Size of view it is Retina 4 full screen . The w and h of view are 320/548. The image  w and h are 320/204. The table view w and h are 320/355 .The table view starts from 202 x = 0 , y = 202. It seems corect to me . I set it to freeform and nothing changed.

Comment: Autolayout is unchecked , I think if I check it it won t run on my iphone that is iphone 4 with 5.1. I also changed image  to check if it is corrupted and it does not work also .

Comment: you set it to free form now set the height of xib to 480 and then reset the image and table heights again

Comment: and also check the contentview mode of imageview in xib ? whats it set to ?

Comment: I found it .....My  big mistake ...the view from file s owner was dragged to table view instead of view ....my junior mistake